# How to change the table name during the runtime

Tags: oracle10g

I have the following,

```
 create table ssrr_emp(
                        Emp_name varchar2(25),
                        Emp_city varchar2(10),
                        Emp_id number(2)
                        );
/


create table ssrr_empsal(
                        sal_grade char(1),
                        salary  number(7,2),
                        Commission number(5)
                        );
/
```

In the above code,the table names are prefixed with ssrr i.e ssrr_emp and ssrr_empsal,

Here my question is when I am executing the above code

I need to prefix the table name with er i.e er_emp and er_empsal.

I mean during the runtime it should ask the name to enter only for ssrr, 
and
if i enter er then the tables should be created in the name er_emp and er_empsal.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL*Plus, you can use substitution variables with `&`, e.g.:

```
create table &&PREFIX._emp(
                    Emp_name varchar2(25),
                    Emp_city varchar2(10),
                    Emp_id number(2)
                    );
/

create table &&PREFIX._empsal(
                    sal_grade char(1),
                    salary  number(7,2),
                    Commission number(5)
                    );
/
```

When you run the script, it will prompt you for the value:

```
Enter value for prefix:
```

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, Thank you for your suggestion its working. Thank you once again.:-)